# Best way to add background image with css3 filters

Tags: css

I currently have this code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: BlinkMacSystemFont,-apple-system,Segoe UI,Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  background: #151626;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.bg {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.bg figure {
  background: url(http://mortenhjort.dk/food/assets/img/login/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  transform: scale(1.05);
  filter: blur(10px);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"><figure></figure></div>
```

The image is used as a sitewide background-image for a new platform and the reason for not just putting it into the body as a background-image is that I want to be able to use the CSS3 Filter (blur) on it + opacity, which for both I plan to animate in certain sections of the site.

However if I do this I have to use absolute positioning for all other content on the site which is kinda messy. Is there a better way to insert this image as a background without using absolute positioning?

I strongly prefer a CSS3-only solution.

Comment: as a pseudo element of body ?

Comment: @vals Yes....:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the image using pseudo element, like this, and you can have other content floating on top.

If you get issues with the `z-index: -1;`, which keep the image to stay in the background, you can remove it and give immediate children of the body `position: relative` instead.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: BlinkMacSystemFont,-apple-system,Segoe UI,Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  background: #151626;
  height: 100vh;
}

body::before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(http://mortenhjort.dk/food/assets/img/login/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  transform: scale(1.05);
  filter: blur(10px);
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -1;
}

div {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>Hey there....</div>
```